# Laravel: Cache just for the script duration - similar to Session::flash

Tags: php, laravel, caching

Does Laravel have any Caching mechanism to cache something just for the duration of the current script/request? Whether that's using a Cache driver like FileCache or DatabaseCache, or just in-memory cache.

For example, I have some data that is quite violate and changes often, and my scripts gets it in multiple places. So I would like to cache it once I got it the first time, but forget it after the execution of the current script has finished (so on next request it fetches it again).

It would be equivalent of me having some global variable `$cache` or similar, where I could store for example `$cache['options']`. Is there something like that in Laravel already?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One way is just following the singleton pattern for the class that does the repeated functionality.

You can also just bind an instance of a class to the Service Container and pull in that dependency where you need to use it.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container

Singleton or instance binding would allow your application to share the same instance of a class anywhere during a single execution.

Comment: Since there are many occasions where same stuff is loaded multiple times, I thought there will be something out-of-the-box that I could use to quickly Cache those, rather than writing new properties etc. But it doesn't seem so, I will write something myself and bind it to the Service Container as per your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could just dump it into $GLOBALS.